# IF Statement help, Triple nested

Tags: if-statement, nested-if

I'm looking to return a value of **0 if** cell **C47** has a value at or below 0, but I keep **getting a return of the negative value of cell E9**. All the other calculations in the formula work great. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'm new to nested IF statements.

```
=IF(C47>0,(IF(C47>$C$3*.8,D47-(F47+$E$9),IF(C47>1,D47-(F47+(SUM($E$6:$E$8))),))))
```

All help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have C47<=1 somewhere in your equation, every reference to C47 is for it being greater to some value, never to it being less then a value. Your nesting also doesn't follow what I usually use. I'm not completely sure of your goal but can lay out a similar example that may help some:

```
 = IF(C47>1, "More then 1",IF(C47>0,"More then 0",IF(C47<=0,"Less then zero","")))
```

Hope this helps some. I think once you move the IFs around a little it will be easier to help you with it.